# How to use a Dictionary or Hashtable for LINQ query performance underneath an OData service

Tags: performance, linq, wcf-data-services, odata

I am very new to OData (only started on it yesterday) so please excuse me if this question is too dumb :-)

I have built a test project as a Proof of Concept for migrating our current web services to OData. For this test project, I am using Reflection Providers to expose POCO classes via OData. These POCO classes come from in-memory cache. Below is the code so far:

```
public class DataSource
{
    public IQueryable<Category> CategoryList
    {
        get
        {
            List<Category> categoryList = GetCategoryListFromCache();
            return categoryList.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
    // below method is only required to allow navigation
    // from Category to Product via OData urls
    // eg: OData.svc/CategoryList(1)/ProductList(2) and so on
    public IQueryable<Category> ProductList
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

[DataServiceKeyAttribute("CategoryId")]
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<Product> ProductList { get; set; }
}

[DataServiceKeyAttribute("ProductId")]
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

To the best of my knowledge, OData is going to use LINQ behind the scenes to query these in-memory objects, ie: List in this case if somebody navigates to OData.svc/CategoryList(1)/ProductList(2) and so on.

Here is the problem though: In the real world scenario, I am looking at over 18 million records inside the cache representing over 24 different entities.

The current production web services make very good use of .NET Dictionary and Hashtable collections to ensure very fast look ups and to avoid a lot of looping. So to get to a Product having ProductID 2 under Category having CategoryID 1, the current web services just do 2 look ups, ie: first one to locate the Category and the second one to locate the Product inside the Category. Something like a btree.

I wanted to know how could I follow a similar architecture with OData where I could tell OData and LINQ to use Dictionary or Hashtables for locating records rather than looping over a Generic List?

Is it possible using Reflection Providers or I am left with no other choice but to write my custom provider for OData?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to process expression trees, so you will need at least partial IQueryable implementation over the underlying LINQ to Objects. For this you don't need a full blown custom provider though, just return you IQueryable from the propties on the context class.
In that IQueryable you would have to recognize filters on the "key" properties (.Where(p => p.ProductID = 2)) and translate that into a dictionary/hashtable lookup. Then you can use LINQ to objects to process the rest of the query.
But if the client issues a query with filter which doesn't touch the key property, it will end up doing a full scan. Although, your custom IQueryable could detect that and fail such query if you choose so.

Comment: great... any examples of this in the real odata world you have come across? i have found none on google so far

Comment: I don't know about a public sample of this. Take a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vitek/archive/2010/02/25/data-services-expressions-part-1-intro.aspx. It in itself describes the expression trees you may encounter. And there's a link there to Matt's blog series about LINQ providers in general as well.